# itunes http link to apps with a keyword

Tags: http, hyperlink, itunes

Is there a way to generate an http link which will open iTunes to the results of a query for apps with a specific keyword.

I have a number of apps and I want my users from my web site to see those with a common keyword. So not to my full list by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker

Search for your company and it will output a direct iTunes link.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in itunes.